# combining mouseenter with if statement?

Tags: javascript

Assume I have 2 div elements. If I `mouseenter` over the first element, I `console.log` a message, and if the second elements, another message.

How come it doesn't work with the pure Javascript below?

It happens to work only if I add an event listener to each individual divs
e.g. `div[0].onmouseenter = function(){}` and `div[1].onmouseenter = function(){}`

Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test1</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");

var test = function(i){
    div[i].onmouseenter = function(){
      if(div[i]===0){
        console.log("success");
      } else if (div[i]===1){
        console.log("another success");
      }
    }
}

for(i=0;i<div.length;i++){
    test(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`div[i]` is a reference to the div.  You're comparing it to a number.  You instead need to compare just `i`:

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
   
var test = function(i){
    div[i].onmouseenter = function(){
      if(i===0){
        console.log("success");
      } else if (i===1){
        console.log("another success");
      }
    }
}
    
for(i=0;i<div.length;i++){
    test(i);
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test1</div>
```